# What to do with my Common Data Crystals?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I currently have all the Basic gear I need for my character and all my companions are equipped to a point that I am happy with (Yavin lockbox gear).

I don't need gear for alts since I only play 3 characters and one is for PvP. I'd rather spend them on something that I can use and/or random stuff to sell for cash. I'm not a big crafter either.

So, what can I spend my Common Data Crystals on now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the only thing you can do is buy Basic gear and sell it back to the vendor after the bind timer expires.  Most other uses involve alts or crafting (using said gear, learning the schematics from it, buying schematics with it).  There are some interesting weapon shells, a speeder, etc. from the CZ-198 vendor that might be of interest.  I believe the level 50 dailies vendor also has a speeder and the Oricon one has pets and gear shells.

Comment: I don't think it is a Bind timer, but more of a Refund timer.

Comment: Yes, my guildies and I use the terms interchangeably since there is no effective difference -- binding the item (via modification, etc.) ends the refund timer.